# what does mean "peripatetic envoys" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Diplomacy – not unlike some other ancient professions – has been around a very long time.
David Reynolds dates its origins back to at least the Bronze Age; documents from the Euphrates kingdom in the mid-8th century BC and from Akhenaten’s Egypt four centuries later reveal a world of **peripatetic envoys, prompted by** matters of peace and war.

does "peripatetic envoys" mean embassies sent to other countries by walking for making peace or war?

Comment: Not literally "walking" but figuratively "traveling".  "Prompted by" refers to the reasons these envoys were sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a definition of peripatetic: "travelling from place to place, in particular working or based in various places for **relatively short periods**". A peripatetic envoy is somebody that is sent to one place or another, unlike an ambassador - "an accredited diplomat sent by a state as its **permanent** representative in a foreign country."

This passage suggests that these envoys were despatched when matters of war or peace required it.